# OSX Format Hard Disk and Reset OSX

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

What is the recommended way to completely erase the Hard Disk and reinstall OSX, as the new OSX does not come on a CD, but an AppStore download I am a bit lost here.

Formatting is clear -- just run disk utility. But how do I then reinstall OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your OSX installation on a USB drive.
http://www.google.com/search?q=USB+drive+osx